# Question over monic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

let $ p $ be a prime number.
Consider $ \Bbb Z_p[x] $. Is possible that for a certain polynomial degree bigger or equal to one ; the only irriducibile polynomials of that degree were non monic?

Comment: If $f(x)=ax^3+bx+c\in \mathbb Z_p[x]$ is irreducible, then $df(x)=dax^3+dbx+dc$ is also irreduccible for, say, non-zero $d\in\mathbb Z_p$ and reciprocally. Take $d$ the inverse of $a$ and $df(x)$ will be monic.

Comment: It's not possible for the same reason this is not possible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ or in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Divide through by the leading coefficient to get a monic irreducible.